# Force Knitr Figure on same page

Tags: plot, knitr

I am using Knitr on RStudio.

```
<<glmall, include=TRUE, fig.align='center', fig.cap='Diagnostics plots for full-model with GLM (Poission)', fig.show='asis'>>=
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(college.glm)
@
```

But my Figure usually gets plotted on the following page, usually occupying the full page. I am not sure how to enforce something like "here" option in TeX (or htb).

Comment: Did you try the `fig.pos` [chunk option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options#chunk_options)?

Comment: @mvkorpel I tried fig.pos='htb!'and It works fine. Thanks